# Use CSS to Modify Radio Buttons without Label fol="id"?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to edit the way radio buttons appear in CSS and trying to do it with the label encompassing the button and not using the label for function.

In other words, I don't want to use this:

```
 <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb2" />
  <label for="rb2">Hello</label>
```

I want to use this:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="rb" />Hello</label>
```

The reason for this is that the HTML is dynamically generated and I cannot create an id or other field in the input.  When I add the css to modify the button/text it doesn't work because it requires the label to be on the text only and "for" to be used.  Here is the CSS:

```
.container{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    border:2px
solid #ccc;
overflow-y: scroll;
resize: both;
}

.container input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check {
  border: 5px solid #0DFF92;
}

.container input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check::before{
  background: #0DFF92;
}

.container input[type=radio]:checked ~ label{
  color: #0DFF92;
}
```

It works if I put the

```
    <div class="container>
<input type="radio" name="rb" value="Hello" id=rb2"/>
      <label for="rb2">Hello</label>
<input type="radio" name="rb" value="Goodbye" id="rb3"/>
      <label for="rb3">Goodbye</label>
</div>
```

But not with

```
    <div class="container>
   <label> <input type="radio" name="rb" value="Hello">Hello</label>
 <label><input type="radio" name="rb" value="Goodbye">Goodbye</label>
    </div>
```

Any suggestions?  Thank you so much!

Comment: If you move your nodes, you must arrange your CSS selectors accordingly. ATM you have: `[radio ]~label` which means that the browser will look for a radio button then target all of its label siblings: ~ You have the labels as parents to radio buttons in second example, but you don't have any CSS that accommodates that layout. In fact, the only advantage of wrapping an input is to increase click area. You don't need a label if you aren't using `for` and input ids. You are clicking the radio directly so just use: `input[type='radio]:checked {color:red}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use javascript. You can't navigate back up the dom tree in css, so since you want the input to be inside the label and the css to affect the label based on the the input, you'd have to use js to detect the change and apply the styling to its parent.

Comment: No problem! You can use jquery, something like `$('input').on('change', function(){ $this.parent().addClass() });` or you can add a style directly to it. Or inside the function, you can check for the value and set the style based on that.